# How to set install privileges conditionally in Wix

Tags: wix, wix3.11

I'm using Wix 3.11 and trying to set the install privileges of my package conditionally.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
<?if Privileged = 0 ?>
  <Package InstallerVersion="405" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perUser" InstallPrivileges="limited" />
<?else ?>
  <Package InstallerVersion="405" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />
<?endif ?>
```

However this doesn't work. When installing, the one with elevated privileges is always picked.
Also, I've tried to create a variable in a .wxi file and set it like this:

.wxi file:

```
<?if Privileged = 0 ?>
  <?define myScope = "perUser" ?>
  <?define myPrivileges = "limited" ?>
<?else?>
  <?define myScope = "perMachine" ?>
  <?define myPrivileges = "elevated" ?>
<?endif?>
```

.wxs file:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="405" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="$(var.myScope)" InstallPrivileges="$(var.myPrivileges)" />
```

But the same happens again: elevated privileges are always picked.
I did my tests on 2 different machines, with non-admin users.

I did not find any solution on the internet so I'm wondering: is it possible to set up a package conditionally?

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**:

I have found the [AdminUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367545(v=vs.85).aspx) property, which seems to be exactly what I need.
I changed my wxs file accordingly to have AdminUser set:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="500" Compressed="yes" />
<SetProperty Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" Sequence="first"/>    
<SetProperty Id="ALLUSERS" Value="2" Sequence="first"/>
<SetProperty Id="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Value="1" Sequence="first"> <![CDATA[NOT AdminUser]]> </SetProperty>
```

When reading the [log file](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/get_a_log.html) of the installation, I noticed AdminUser was set before MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION, and setting MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION wouldn't trigger a reset for AdminUser.

I scheduled my SetProperties to the most prior action I could find, which was "FindRelatedProducts", however AdminUser is set even before that (actually before both installExecuteSequence and installUISequence), I was unable to get MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION set first.

I believe there is no way to determine wether you are running your installation under an admin or a standard session.
If anyone know a solution, please feel free to advise.

Thank you Michael and Brian for your time.

Comment: Look up [MSIINSTALLPERUSER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408007) and the rest of [Single Package Authoring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408068). (Sorry I don't have the time to flesh this out into an answer right now.)

Comment: Michael, thanks for your feeback.
I've been digging into it, and it seems nice, however I couldn't make the Single Package Authoring indications into a solution. I'll edit my original post accordingly to explain what I did.

Comment: These are also preprocessor directives and are set at compile time, not runtime. there should be some well-defined mechanism for doing this since several installers I've used in the past have the "per-user or all user" radio button selection in them.

Comment: Brian, you are right. Unfortunately I need Wix to detect on its own wether the installation should be per machine or user, and I cannot use any radio buttons in my UI.

Comment: As Brian says, your approach is trying to use a build-time conditional for a run-time condition. (AdminUser is a run-time property.) Instead of `<?if ... ?>` you need to use [SetProperty](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/setproperty.html) actions (or control events if you ever put it in the UI) sequenced with a condition that references, e.g., AdminUser.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't.
I have never been able to set the property during the installation. See my edit for details.